# Flatten List<string[]> into single string with one line for each element

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I have an instance of type `List<string[]>` I would to convert this to a string with a each `string[]` on a newline. I'm using the following LINQ query to flatten out the list however I'm not sure how I can add a new line between each `string[]` without expanding my query into something far more ugly. Is there a way to do it without gutting my query and using `String.Join` or `IEnumberable.Aggregate` inside a `foreach` loop?

```
results.SelectMany(x => x).Aggregate((c, n) => c + ", " + n)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample output? Input would also be nice.

Comment: @Xcelled194 I could but there are already two working answers.

Comment: There weren't when I posted the comment. :P You should still add some, to help future searchers with the same problem.

Comment: Cmon you are putting form over function here.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal fair enough :P

Comment: @ja72 I think the accepted answer gives you the best of both. I'm not putting form over function, I already know how to do it with iteration. My code uses LINQ over iteration, I want to follow that convention, just trying to expand my skill set. Writing something that works would be no problem.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Select(a => String.Join(", ", a)));
```

Complete sample:

```
var results = new List<string[]> {
    new[]{"this", "should", "be", "on"},
    new[]{"other", "line"}
};

var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                         results.Select(a => String.Join(", ", a)));
```

Result:

```
this, should, be, on
other, line
```

**UPDATE** Here is aggregation done right - it uses [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to build single string in memory

```
results.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                  (sb, a) => sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", a)),
                  sb => sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Good call... I feel dumb asking the question after seeing how simple the solution is :|

Comment: @evanmcdonnal yep :) BTW String.Join is efficient also - it does not produce tons of strings while joining.

Comment: I was actually considering opening another question about the differences in IL produced by `String.Join` and `Aggregate` for concatenation... Maybe I'll have to.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal strings in .NET are immutable, so concatenating strings with `+` produces new string in memory each time. If you want to avoid this, you need to use StringBuilder (something like mutable string) or String.Join - both work with pointers and memory allocation for single string in memory

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I've updated answer with solution which uses StringBuilder for aggreagation

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It's worth noting that `string.Join` will actually be *more* efficient than a string builder.  A StringBuilder will allocate a lot less intermediate arrays than naive string concatenation will, but `string.Join` can actually determine the exact number of characters in the output from the very start, thus allowing it to create no intermediate string buffers at all, but rather create the one buffer of exactly the right size right from the start.

Answer (score 3):

```
results.Select(sa => sa.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b))
       .Aggregate((c, d) => c + Enviroment.NewLine + d);
```

Comment: Note that this solution is *dramatically* less efficient than the posted solution using `String.Join` as it will create a *lot* of intermediate strings, which will result in a lot of unnecessary copying of memory, and a much higher consumption of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use also extension methods for this flattening of a collection of string, and also be allowed to specify a line separator. Note the use of Trim here as we will have a trailing separator at the very end otherwise.

```
using System.Text;

namespace MultiLingual.Translator.Lib
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Merges a collection of lines into a flattened string separating each line by a specified line separator.
        /// Newline is deafult
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputLines"></param>
        /// <param name="lineSeparator"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string? FlattenString(this IEnumerable<string>? inputLines, string lineSeparator = "\n")
        {
            if (inputLines == null || !inputLines.Any())
            {
                return null;
            }
            var flattenedString = inputLines?.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                (sb, l) => sb.AppendLine(l + lineSeparator),
                sb => sb.ToString().Trim());

            return flattenedString;
        }

    }
}
```

Usage in a XUnit Test of mine :

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("Jeg er fra Norge og jeg liker brunost", "i'm from norway and i like brown cheese")]
        public async Task TranslationReturnsExpected(string input, string expectedTranslation)
        {
            string? translation = await _translateUtil.Translate(LanguageCode.English, input, LanguageCode.Norwegian);
            translation.Should().NotBeNull();
            translation.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedTranslation);
        }
```